# Linq getting a child list after group by and join

Tags: c#, linq

I needed to send `ColorModel` to web page to find `Stock` for each `Shoe`. I want to get a list of child for the `ColorModel` but don't know how.
Here are the table and model classes:

```cs
public class ColorModel
{
    public int ShoeId { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public string? ColorName { get; set; } = null!;

    public List<SizeModel> Sizes { get; set; }
}

public class SizeModel
{
    public int? SizeId { get; set; }
    public float? SizeValue { get; set; }
    public int? Stock { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public partial class ShoeVariant
{
    public int ShoeVariantId { get; set; }
    public int ShoeId { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Shoe Shoe { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Size Size { get; set; } = null!;
}

public partial class Shoe
{
    public int ShoeId { get; set; }
    public string ShoeName { get; set; } = null!;
}

public partial class Size
{
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public float SizeValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShoeVariant> ShoeVariants { get; set; } = new List<ShoeVariant>();
}
```

```cs
var result = (
    from sv in _context.ShoeVariants
    join s in _context.Shoes on sv.ShoeId equals s.ShoeId
    join color in _context.Colors on sv.ColorId equals color.ColorId
    join sz in _context.Sizes on sv.SizeId equals sz.SizeId
    group sv by new {s.ShoeId, color.ColorId, color.ColorName} into g
    select new ColorModel
    {
        ShoeId = g.Key.ShoeId,
        ColorId = g.Key.ColorId,
        ColorName = g.Key.ColorName,
        Sizes = new List<SizeModel>
        {
        }
    }).ToList();
```

Should I just do separate select to get list for each SizeModel?
`Stock` value is in `ShoeVariants`

Comment: Take a look at `SelectMany`.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Can you provide an expected result please?

Comment: Probably you do not need joins and grouping either. Better show your classes used in this query.

Comment: @Dani I want to select ColorModel class like above that have a list of SizeModel from query. Like: {ShoeId: 1, ColorId: 1, ColorName: "Blue", Sizes:{ {SizeId: 1, SizeValue: 34, Stock: 3},{SizeId: 2, SizeValue: 35, Stock: 2}}}

Comment: If you really expect correct answer, add model classes. I'm interested in navigation properties.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv those are my model classes. The table is more looked like this: public partial class ShoeVariant
{
    public int ShoeVariantId { get; set; }

    public int ShoeId { get; set; }

    public int ColorId { get; set; }

    public int SizeId { get; set; }

    public int Stock { get; set; }

    public virtual Color Color { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Shoe Shoe { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Size Size { get; set; } = null!;
}

Comment: @FishThing, you can edit your question and add these classes. Comments is not proper place for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should evaluate grouping on the client side. SQL do not have analogue which returns grouping detail.

```cs
var variants = _context.ShoeVariants
    .Select(sv => new 
    {
        ShoeId = sv.ShoeId,
        ColorId = sv.ColorId,
        ColorName = sv.Color.Name,

        Size = new SizeModel
        {
            SizeId = sv.SizeId,
            SizeValue = sv.Size.SizeValue,
            Stock = sv.Stock
        }
    })
    .AsEnumerable();

var result = variants
    .GroupBy(v => new { v.ShoeId, v.ColorId, v.ColorName })
    .Select(g => new ColorModel
    {
        ShoeId = g.Key.ShoeId,
        ColorId = g.Key.ColorId,
        ColorName = g.Key.ColorName,

        Sizes = g.Select(x => x.Size).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This worked thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some navigation in your models:

```
public class ShoeVariant{
   
   ....
   public int ShoeId {get; set;}
   public Shoe Shoe {get; set;}
   ...

}
public class Shoe{
   
   ....
   public List<ShoeVariant> ShoeVariants {get; set;}
   ...

}
```

after that, you can use **SelectMany** for your inner list:

```
select new ColorModel
    {
        ShoeId = g.Key.ShoeId,
        ColorId = g.Key.ColorId,
        ColorName = g.Key.ColorName,
        Sizes = g.SelectMany(m=>m.Sizes)
    }
```

note:
I prefer MethodStyle instead of QueryStyle, which makes it more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Sorry for not providing more details about that. Those model classes are the one I want to select to send but the table is like this: public partial class ShoeVariant
{
    public int ShoeVariantId { get; set; }
    public int ShoeId { get; set; }
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public int SizeId { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public virtual Color Color { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Shoe Shoe { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Size Size { get; set; } = null!;
}

Comment: It's okay, but for using this type of query you have to let EF know about your navigation specification. In model navigation configuration, you have to add navigation property on both sides of relations. in your case, a property in the type of ICollection<ShoeVarient> should be added to Size, Color and Shoe model class.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships